# Typoscript add class to the first element using stdWrap

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have a custom requirement to display an image slider using TypoScript. The images are taken from default tt_content image content element.

I've added the following TypoScript code to implement this;

```
lib.homeslider = COA
lib.homeslider {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {    
            where = colPos = 3
            andWhere = deleted = 0
            andWhere = hidden = 0
            orderBy = rand()
        }
        renderObj =  FILES
        renderObj {
            references {
                table = tt_content
                fieldName = image
            }
            renderObj = IMAGE
            renderObj {
                file.import.data = file:current:uid
                file.treatIdAsReference = 1
                stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
                stdWrap.wrap = <div class="item active">|</div>|*|<div class="item">|</div>|*|<div class="item">|</div>
            }
        }
    }
    wrap = <div id="carousel-example-generic" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade"><div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">|</div></div>
}
```

This displayed the images in frontend. But my requirement is I want to add class "active" to the first image wrapper. I've added the following code to implement this, but not working.

```
stdWrap.wrap = <div class="item active">|</div>|*|<div class="item">|</div>|*|<div class="item">|</div>
```

Final HTML output I need to generate is;

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
   <div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active"> 
            <a href="#">
                 <img src="images/temp/startbild1.jpg" alt="#">
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
           <a href="#">
                <img src="images/temp/startbild2.jpg" alt="#">
           </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
                 <img src="images/temp/startbild3.jpg" alt="#">
            </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If anybody knows the solution, then please help me.

Comment: This is called OptionSplit, see http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ObjectsAndProperties/Index.html. Are you sure you need it in the IMAGE renderobj? I'd say it should go in the FILES renderObj. Just guessing though. What output do you get?

Comment: @Urs: I need a slider with tt_content images. Basically image tags are wrapped with a div <div class="item> and bootstrap slider loaded. For this I need to add "active" class for the first element. Thats why I am trying this.
Can you give me an example how it can be achieved using optionsplit or any other methods?

Comment: I know. try moving the line  `stdWrap.wrap = <div` up, just before the line `renderObj = IMAGE ` and see what it does. Please also include the HTML output you get in the question. Also, can't you use `.carousel-inner div:first-of-type` in CSS as an alternative?

Comment: @Urs: Using CSS is a last method of try if no other options. I've edited the above code and added the final HTML output I need to generate. As per your feedback, I've placed stdWrap.wrap = <div just above the line renderObj = IMAGE. But it adds the class "active" to all the elements. Do you have any other idea to solve this?

Comment: The idea was that you'd post the OUTPUT you get, so users can look at it without reproducing it in an own site. Another time, try posting the problem, the current result, and the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original TS is fine.

Supposing you have the images in the same CE (Content element), not in several CEs. As such:

[image]

For easier readability, I have modified the following line:

```
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="item active">A|ENDA</div>|*|<div class="item">B|ENDB</div>|*|<div class="item">C|ENDC</div>
```

Which gives me:

```
<div id="c1531" class="csc-default">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
    <div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">A<img src="index.php?eID=dumpFile&amp;t=p&amp;p=1106&amp;token=a71bae9f5bfc837dce6b7974e6f63aca5cc656ae" width="165" height="158"   alt="" >ENDA</div>
      <div class="item">C<img src="index.php?eID=dumpFile&amp;t=p&amp;p=1107&amp;token=0dab49e1d8dac7c8cfd7a7910133cb2398c19030" width="420" height="132"   alt="" >ENDC</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: try for random content

```
lib.homeslider = COA
lib.homeslider {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {    
            where = colPos = 3
            andWhere = deleted = 0
            andWhere = hidden = 0
        }
        renderObj =  FILES
        renderObj {
            maxItems = 2 #as many as you want
            sorting = rand #not working, maybe with EXT:lvrandfiles
            references {
                table = tt_content
                fieldName = image
            }            
            renderObj = IMAGE
            renderObj {
                file.import.data = file:current:uid
                file.treatIdAsReference = 1

                stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
                stdWrap.wrap = <div class="item active">A|ENDA</div>|*|<div class="item">B|ENDB</div>|*|<div class="item">C|ENDC</div>
          }
        }
    }
    wrap = <div id="carousel-example-generic" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade"><div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">|</div></div>
}
```

Comment: Hi Urs, Thank you very much. I've added the images in same CE and added your above script. Its working great...:) One more doubt..I've added an orderBy = rand() to order the images randomly..But when I add images in a single CE, its not working..Do you've any idea?

Comment: This script not working for me. stdWrap.listNum = rand

Comment: It seems that listNum is not available in FILES and IMAGE objects. I'd have gone for `sorting = rand`, but that doesn't seem to be implemented, as there's an extension that does, http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/lvrandfiles. Be careful with such one-trick-pony extensions, as the more you pile up, the less maintainable your site will become. You might want to find out why that's not (yet) in the core. I'm adding the not-working TS anyway.

Comment: Thanks Urs. I'll look for another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the correct script;

```
lib.homeslider = COA_INT
lib.homeslider {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {    
            where = colPos = 3
            andWhere = deleted = 0
            andWhere = hidden = 0
            orderBy = rand()
        }
        renderObj =  FILES
        renderObj {
            references {
                table = tt_content
                fieldName = image
            }
            stdWrap.wrap = |###SPLITTER###
            renderObj = IMAGE
            renderObj {
                file.import.data = file:current:uid
                file.treatIdAsReference = 1
                altText.data = file:current:title
                stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
            }
        }
        stdWrap.split {
            token = ###SPLITTER###
            cObjNum = 1 |*| 2 |*| 3 || 4
            1.current = 1
            1.wrap = <div class="item active">|</div>

            2.current = 1
            2.wrap = <div class="item">|</div>

            3.current = 1
            3.wrap = <div class="item">|</div>

            4.current = 1
        }
    }
    wrap = <div id="carousel-example-generic" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade"><div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">|</div></div>
}
```